# Mixed content in console with PrestaShop website

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-devtools, prestashop-1.6

I can't figure out (trace) where external sources (fonts) over `http` are coming from.  The console suggests that it is coming from the first line of the document, which looks like this:
`<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="lt-ie"> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html  lang="nl" class=""><!--<![endif]-->`
 But I guess Chrome doesn't know where to point either..

I have been trying to switch off some modules, clean up javascript that seemed suspicious and or was lately added, but nothing really helps.

Example from the Chrome console:

[image: Example from the Chrome console]

Question: how the track down the script/code that causes these fonts to be loaded.

This might be just a PrestaShop specific question, but I hope there are other methods to find the script(s).

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. The first thing I would try is going to "Network" panel and checking
   the "initiator" column for the resources in question.
2. The "fonts" could be a tricky thing to track. You should try searching across CSS files for a web font name - this usually helps.

**Hint**: requests could be filtered by type via filters on the top.

[image: Font requests]

Comment: The filter is nice, never used it before. But it still leads me to the first line of the index file. I searched across all css files, for `google` `woff`.

Comment: That means that it is being injected somehow and the system doesn't have a good reference to it. Maybe an `eval()` is occurring somewhere that injects it. Also remember that redirects could occur for the fonts from another URL provided. You'd be better off searching the *name* of the fonts in question and see if that pops anything up, it would be more accurate.

Comment: Yeah, I though about downloading all the files of the whole website, and then opening all css and js files in Notepad++ and then search(!). I sometimes do this.. But we're talking about loads of files. Maybe Someone has a suggestion for this?

Comment: Try hitting "Ctrl-Shift-F" and search for ".woff". Doesn't it find anything? If you can provide any link, it would help as well.